# I have a text file which begins with LZ2TreeFile. How do I open and read it correctly in Linux or Windows?

Tags: file, text, notepad++

If I try to open with notepad++ or Kwrite, it displays some characters properly but mostly it is garbled characters. I tried several encoding options apart from utf-8 and it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: We need more details. If you have it on Linux, try a od -xa LZ2TreeFile.???  | head -20  to hex dump it's start with Ascii.

Comment: Also, just roun the Linux "file" command on the file to see if file can identify it's type better.

Comment: Running the file command on the file tells me that its a MS-DOS executable (built-in)

Comment: Running the od command as you specified, shows me, 0000000    5a4c    5432    6572    4665    6c69    2065    0d7b    200a
          L   Z   2   T   r   e   e   F   i   l   e  sp   {  cr  nl  sp
0000020    3343    6144    6174    0a60    2005

Comment: And some more hex and ASCII values for the rest of the text.

Comment: Looks like it might be a self-extracting archive (the executable part) using LZ2 compression... something I can't remember dealing with. But 7zip (7z) claims to handle LZ2 files so give 7zip a try to see if it handles the file. 7zip is available under both Linux and Windows. If you really trust the file you can just execute the thing under Windows... but unpacking with 7z is FAR safer.

Comment: Yes, I actually tried it before. It doesn't recognize it as a valid archive file.

Comment: Kind of lost here if 7z doesn't handle it. You need to ask how much do you trust the file and how badly do you want to open it. In your searchings note that lz2 and lz78 are aliases. perhaps legroom.net/software/uniextract might help on Windows. Perhaps running from command line under Lnux WIne to try and be safe? Safer would be setting up a VM (like VirtualBox) with FreeDOS and running it with the virtual network cable "unplugged".

Comment: Was this file a Crimson `.cd3` file by any chance?